# Gradle: how to include external project dependency in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have got two projects:

```
Project_A 
  core
  other
```

and

```
Project_B
  foo
```

These are two separate projects hosted in two different git repositories. `Project_B/foo` has a SNAPSHOT-dependency on `Project_A/core`. I use IntelliJ as IDE. We publish snapshots of `Project_A/core` whenever there is change that needs to be propagated to `Project_B/foo`.  Sometimes the change rate in `Project_A/core` is so high that it would save a lot of time to have them in one IDEA project so that we can navigate back and forth and the changes are visible without publishing snapshots. 
How can I mount these two projects as one project in IDE? I have tried the following:

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution.all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
        if (dependency.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && dependency.requested.group == "bar.com" && dependency.requested.module == "core") {
            def targetProject = findProject(":${dependency.requested.module}")
            if (targetProject != null) {
                dependency.useTarget targetProject
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit odd. The title suggests that you have trouble to include dependencies at all and doesn't mention a specific IDE. IntelliJ Idea isn't the only IDE out there. In eclipse the solution to your question would be easy. Use composite builds and import both projects into the IDE, done ...

Comment: @noamik see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm well aware that IntelliJ supports composite builds as well. I just am not sufficiently familiar with it to provide an answer to the question. I was just pointing out to naimdjon that he might want to name the IDE he is asking for in the title, which he did in the meantime.

Comment: Jepp. Thanks for pointing that out @noamik.